Attempt at proving pigeonhole principle via induction
I have attempted a proof of the pigeonhole principle. Am I overlooking some logical gap?
I was reading through Biggs' proof in "Discrete Mathematics" but the formulation there was somewhat different.
The pigeonhole principle is formulated here as

If there is an injection from $\mathbb{N}_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ to $\mathbb{N}_m = \{ 1,2, \ldots, m \}$,
then $n \leq m$.


Let $m$ be a given natural number. We want to prove the following statement for each natural $n$:

$P(n): \text{ there exists an injection from } \mathbb{N}_n \text{ to } \mathbb{N}_m \implies n \leq m$

We will use induction. $P(1)$ is true, trivially so, since $m \geq 1$ is always true.
Suppose now $P(n)$ holds; the task then is to prove $P(n+1)$.
So, say there is an injection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}_{n+1}$ to $\mathbb{N}_m$.
Consider the new auxiliary function $g$ from $\mathbb{N}_n$ to $\mathbb{N}_m$ where for a natural $x$ between $1$ and $n$, we define $g(x) = f(x)$. Essentially $g$ is a restriction of $f$ to the subset $\mathbb{N}_n \subset \mathbb{N}_{n+1}$.
Injectivity of $g$ is inherited from $f$. So we have exhibited an injection, namely $g$, from $\mathbb{N}_n$ to $\mathbb{N}_m$. Since $P(n)$ is true by hypothesis, we conclude $n \leq m$.
Now we will rule out the case $n = m$. If $n = m$ then we cannot assign a value to $f(n+1)$ anywhere in $\mathbb{N}_m$ without violating injectivity of $f$. Hence we must have $ n < m$, that is, $ n +1 \geq m$. This proves $P(n+1)$, and we are thus done.

I've gone ahead and added [tag:solution-verification] since this is what you're asking about. Let me then quote from the tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' Please identify a specific doubt.

In any case, let me (a) nitpick that $g$ is not "essentially" the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{N}_n$, it is this restriction identically, and (b) "if $n = m$ then we cannot assign a value to $f(n + 1)$ anywhere in $\mathbb{N}_m$ without violating injectivity of $f$" is in need of justification.

@BenSteffan: Fair. I had no specific doubt about it overall, I think the arguments should work (as opposed to Biggs' formulation, which I deem more complicated).

@BenSteffan: Ah alright the thing about $f(n+1)$ is a fair objection. I would say: since $f$ is injective, the values $f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n)$ are an $n$ number of distinct values in $\mathbb{N}_m$, and since $m = n$, there are no other possible for $f$ to attain. Hence $f(n+1)$ must belong to $ { f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n) } $, but then we would have $f(n+1) = f(k)$ for some natural $k \neq n+1$, which violates injectivity. Would that suffice?

@kapython I personally think it's sufficient, but this depends on what standards of rigor you hold yourself to. To really make it formal, you should prove that the image of an injection $A \to B$ always has cardinality $|A|$, but this is essentially the pigeonhole principle, since it directly entails that $|B| \leq |A|$. That's what Prem means when they say that there is a "disguised PHP" in your proof.

Proving Pigeon Hole Principle can not (should not) use PHP itself.
The fault lies within the last Section :
"Now we will rule out the case $n=m$ :
If $n=m$ then we cannot assign a value to $f(n+1)$ anywhere in $\mathbb N_m$ without violating injectivity of $f$
Hence we must have $n<m$ , that is, $n+1≥m$
This proves $P(n+1)$ , and we are thus done"
Check the highlighted argument.
It is "Disguised PHP" hiding there !
It is just claiming that "We can not put $n+1$ Numbers into $n$ Slots without having at least $2$ Numbers in at least $1$ Slot" which is essentially PHP.
Proving PHP using PHP is Circular
ADDENDUM :
OP : Am I overlooking some logical gap?
In addition to the Crucial fault given here , we should also use Induction on $m$ , though that is a relatively minor fault here.

Hm interesting, did not realize a circular argument might be lurking. Is this addendum free from using the pigeonhole principle? Since $f$ is injective, the values $f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n)$ are an $n$ number of distinct values in $\mathbb{N}_m$, and since $m = n$, there are no other possible for $f$ to attain. Hence $f(n+1)$ must belong to $ { f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n) } $, but then we would have $f(n+1) = f(k)$ for some natural $k \neq n+1$, which violates injectivity. Does this argument not free it from circularity?

To restate what I said in a comment above here for completeness: "Since f is injective, the values $f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n)$ are an $n$ number of distinct values in $\mathbb{N}_m$" is basically the same as the pigeonhole principle: If you know that the image of $f$ has cardinality $n$, then it immediately follows that $n \leq m$ and the rest of your proof is superfluous, q.e.d. But that this is the case is something you need to prove in this context (one may object that it's "obvious," but so is the pigeonhole principle).

Your answer should probably make this explicit, Prem. Right now you're just boldly stating that there is a disguised use of the premise there and that the proof is circular, but you're not really backing this up with anything. Also, I see no reason to use induction on $m$ here, and not using it is not a fault. (Also, in matters of style, less boldface shouting and more writing in structured paragraphs would perhaps make the answer better received.)
